# Find country perimeter lengths using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I have polygons representing world countries and I am attempting to find the length of their borders in miles
I have tried
using `ST_Perimeter`

```sql
SELECT ST_Perimeter(geom::geography) * 0.000621371  AS dist
FROM   countries
WHERE  cntry_name = 'Ireland'
```

and using `ST_Boundary`

```sql
SELECT ST_Length(ST_Boundary(geom)) *  0.000621371 as dist
FROM   countries
WHERE  cntry_name = 'Ireland'
```

but continually get a result which is inaccurate.
What is the correct way to find total length around a polygon/country?

Comment: What is the SRID of the geometry? `select st_srid(geom) from countries limit 1`

Comment: what answer do you get compared to what you expect?

Comment: Which polygons are you using? They may be inaccurate due to simplification.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the boundaries of a country is actually often an approximation, and depend a lot of the precision of your geometry and the way it was measured in your reference. If you measure precisely the actual limit, even something that seems like a right line can be decomposed in little parts (following every rock, every little move of a river, ...) that are not completly right, and in the end you add up a lot of km.

A famous example is the fact that [Lewis Fry Richardson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Fry_Richardson#Research_on_the_length_of_coastlines_and_borders) wanted to measure the coasts of the british island and ends up comparing it to a fractal. Meaning you can have as much kilometers that you want using a more precise geometry.

In the end, you need to define the precision of the geometry used for your test and for the reference if you want to have a comparable distance. If your geometry is too precise, you can for example use the [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_Simplify.html) function to simplify a geometry and remove some precision. The other way around, adding precision, is of course not possible.